# Can't find uploaded file on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have uploaded a php file on wordpress, although I can edit and update the file from WP File Manager I am unable to find the page on the internet.
When I see the info of the file, it displays a link to the file and that link leads to nowhere, it says "500:Internal Error".
I have also uploaded a html type file to my WP File Manager which is accessible from the internet, but the php file is not.
[This](http://kirtidevelopers.com/newwp/wp-content/themes/kback/chimp.php) is the link to the file which I uploaded.
Any help would be appreciated.
[This is the screenshot of my WP File Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aph3A.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have just clicked the link to the chimp.php file and it loaded fine so I dont see an issue here. Sometimes I have noticed that uploads are not instantaneous, and can take a few minutes before the changes take affect.

Comment: can you please review the link. I forgot to update the link here, I have just changed the location of my file in WP File Manager. I was trying to do some experiments, in some hope that it works, but its not working. Thank You.

Comment: Adding the Kirti directory to the URL makes the page visible http://kirtidevelopers.com/newwp/wp-content/themes/kirti/kback/chimp.php

Comment: actually that was not the page I was trying to find, that is another page. In my php file which I have mentioned above contains some functions and a single echo statement. 
Please help, I tried to upload my site on 000Webhost and when I open my php page as mentioned above it was visible from my browser, but not on my wordpress domain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I see a 500 error but the url path isn't including the kirti extension. Just want to narrow down the problem but have you created the page in the wp-admin page menu?